# JUnit assert equals to a Joda DateTime (with time zone)

Tags: java, datetime, junit, jodatime

I recept a joda Datetime from REST Web Service and I want asset this date. I have a problem of

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2017-07-13 09:58:19");
Assert.assertEquals(dt, entity.getBody().get(0).getDate());
```

I have this error trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2017-07-13T09:58:19.000+02:00> but was:<2017-07-13T09:58:19.000Z>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the timezone issue:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-07-13 09:58:19", formatter);
Assert.assertEquals(dt, entity.getBody().get(0).getDate().toLocalDateTime());
```

Comment: is it better but I have java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2017-07-13T09:58:19.000> but was:<2017-07-13T09:58:19.000Z>

Comment: @sgrillon add `.toLocalDateTime()` as above